# iOS save in-app purchases on server

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm encountering a big problem on my app : I had to make in app purchases (non-renewing subscription), and I want the user retrieving his subscription when the app is deleted and reinstalled on the device. I haven't account system for this app, so it's hard. I wonder if I can still use a server which is going to store all subscriptions, but I don't get how I can make a unique id for each user, and retrieve it when the app is deleted. I searched with the app store receipt (containing all purchases) but when I write this code to get it, it returns nil :

```
let receiptUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL
    var receipt: NSData
    do {
        receipt = try NSData(contentsOfURL: receiptUrl!, options: NSDataReadingOptions())
    } catch _ {
        receipt = NSData()
    }

    let receiptdata: NSString = receipt.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

    print(receiptdata)
```

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Are you using a Web-Server to fetch the information of the user ?

Comment: No, I'm not getting informations on the user.

Comment: You really need a user account if you are using non-renewing subscriptions. If you don't have a user account you don't have anything to associate the subscription with so how can you identify your user when they reinstall?

Comment: Thanks for your response, is there a way to make user connect with his iCloud account to save the subscription ?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible to get the users `DSPersonID` (unique ID associated with an iTunes account) from the receipt, there is a nice blog post about it here: https://magervalp.github.io/2013/03/19/poking-around-in-masreceipts.html.

With the `DSPersonID` you can uniquely identify the iTunes user.

**Warning** this is not documented and it is entirely possible it will change in the future, use it at your own risk.